# Finding the position of a character within a string

Tags: r, string

I am trying to find the equivalent of the ANYALPHA SAS function in R.  This function searches a character string for an alphabetic character, and returns the first position at which at which the character is found.

Example:  looking at the following string '123456789A', the ANYALPHA function would return 10 since first alphabetic character is at position 10 in the string.  I would like to replicate this function in R but have not been able to figure it out.  I need to search for any alphabetic character regardless of case (i.e. [:alpha:])

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: how about `regexpr("A", "123456789A")[1]`? Returns the value `10`

Comment: Here's a function for you `anyalpha <- function(txt) regexpr("[[:alpha:]]", txt)[1]`

Comment: Perfect, they both work great (I changed the "A" to "[[alpha]]" in the first example and it worked great.  I think I will end up using the function.  Thank you both!

Comment: `c(regexpr("[[:alpha:]]", txt))` would also do it, as `c()` strips attributes

Comment: Thank you for the comment about wrapping it in c() to strip attributes.  I'm new at R and have lots to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an `anyalpha` function. I added a few extra features. You can specify the maximum amount of matches you want in the `n` argument, it defaults to `1`. You can also specify if you want the position or the value itself with `value=TRUE`:

```
anyalpha <- function(txt, n=1, value=FALSE) {
  txt <- as.character(txt)
  indx <- gregexpr("[[:alpha:]]", txt)[[1]]
  ret <- indx[1:(min(n, length(indx)))]

  if(value) {
    mapply(function(x,y) substr(txt, x, y), ret, ret)
    } else {ret}
}

#test
x <-  '123A56789BC'
anyalpha(x)
#[1] 4
anyalpha(x, 2)
#[1]  4 10
anyalpha(x, 2, value=TRUE)
#[1] "C" "A"
```